# JavaScript - diferent execute/load-order in diferent browsers

Tags: javascript, load-order

Does anybody have any idea why the following code will be executed in different order in different browsers? Code is in an external file embedded in a plain HTML page between `<body></body>` using  `<script src="js/filename.js"></script>`.

```
document.write("This is the first document.write()");

document.write("<br />followed by a second doc.write with br-element before");

document.write("<br /> and a third one doc.write with br before");

alert("now comes an alert() as fourth (will be expected)");

document.write("<br /> then there will be a fifth doc.write after the first alert");

document.write("<br />and a one more (sixth) doc.write after which an alert will be expected");

alert("the second alert at seventh position");

document.write("<br />and now the eight doc.write after the seventh alert");
```

Chrome executes the alerts at first followed by the docWrites, Edge execute the first 3 docWrite's, then both alerts and then the other docWrite's (also wrong order). Only Firefox execute this code in the right order.

Same behavior is when I execute similar code in developer tool of the browser(s)
for example: write in one line an `document.write()`; followed by an `alert()`. Chrome will execute the `alert()` as first...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Writing to the document is an internal process--it may be buffering, for example. Threads like https://forums.asp.net/t/955514.aspx?document+write+doesn+t+write+until+javascript+function+terminates+ may help, but please take note of what's discussed in the whatwg living spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#dom-document-write

Comment: I'm pretty certain the statements are executed in order, but the document might not yet be re-rendered when the `alert()` box appears. Notice that both `document.write` and `alert` are outdated and bad practices, don't use them.

Comment: Tnx both of you. @Bergi, yes I know it is bad practice to use both. I just tried some fundamentals and thorough this testings I figgured out this behavior and I did not understand WHY this happens. But you gived to me a good idea with loading of the document and also Dave's links was helpfull. Now I can "imagine" why browser makes so stupind things. This is why I love JS so much. The results sometimes have so suprising effects :-)))

Comment: @AJS I'm not so sure about that. I think this is purely an odd buffering effect. None of the code written here should be performed asynchronously.